# How do i set the length of like counts

Tags: python, html, django, jinja2

i am new on Django and i am working on a website where users like posts. I have an issue on how i can set the length of like counts before 'Likes' will be removed and show only the like counts. When a user do not click on Like button it displays 'LIKE' at the side of like button, but when a user clicked on the like button it displays the like count to 1 without 'LIKE' at the side of the count, because i am using an else statement. How do i display 'LIKE' at the side of like count. For example; '1 Liked' Then when 100 users clicked on like button, like counts: '100'. But if it is less than 100, like count will be '99 Liked'

[image to help](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WSpLt.jpg)

```py
{% if post.liked_by_user %}
    <button type="submit" name="post_id" value="{{ post.id }}" class="like float-left pl-2" >
    <img src="{{ '/static/' }}images/heart_empty.png" width="24" height="24">
    </button>
    {% if post.likes.all %}
        <a href="{% url 'site:likes_users' post.id %}" class="like-count font-small dark-grey-text font-weight-bold">
        <span class="d-inline-block text-truncate" style="max-width:70px;position:relative;top:3px;">
        {{ post.likes.count }} 
        </span>
        </a>
    {% else %}
        <span class="like-count font-small dark-grey-text font-weight-bold">Like</span>
    {% endif %}
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use another `if` statement to know when the like count is smaller than `100`. If it is then put `"Liked"` next to it and if it isn't don't.

```py
{% if post.liked_by_user %}
    <button type="submit" name="post_id" value="{{ post.id }}" class="like float-left pl-2" >
    <img src="{{ '/static/' }}images/heart_empty.png" width="24" height="24">
    </button>
    {% if post.likes.all %}
        {% if post.likes.count >= 100 %}
            <a href="{% url 'site:likes_users' post.id %}" class="like-count font-small dark-grey-text font-weight-bold">

            <span class="d-inline-block text-truncate" style="max-width:70px;position:relative;top:3px;">
            {{ post.likes.count }} 
            </span>
            </a>
        {% else %}
            <a href="{% url 'site:likes_users' post.id %}" class="like-count font-small dark-grey-text font-weight-bold">

            <span class="d-inline-block text-truncate" style="max-width:70px;position:relative;top:3px;">
            {{ post.likes.count }} Liked
            </span>
            </a>
        {% endif %}
    {% else %}
        <span class="like-count font-small dark-grey-text font-weight-bold">Like</span>
    {% endif %}
{% endif %}
```

This is a simple app that I made in Flask to help you:

**templates/base.html**:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    {% if likes %}
        {% if likes < 5 %}
            <span>{{ likes }} Liked</span>
        {% else %}
            <span>{{ likes }}</span>
        {% endif %}
    {% else %}
        <span>Like</span>
    {% endif %}
</body>
</html>
```

**app.py**:

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def homepage():
    likes = 4
    return render_template("base.html", likes=likes)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host="localhost", port="5000")
```

When likes is smaller than `5`, for example `4` then it is printed out like `4 Liked`. When it is equal to or bigger than `5`, then only the like count is printed.

Comment: @Fillip..this is not displaying anything. it still show the numbers less than 100 without Liked.

Comment: @MrHize Oh sorry I made it backwards. Numbers bigger than 100 will have Liked next to it. I made the Flask app to help you do it yourself, so you can understand what I did. I edited the answer.

Comment: @MrHize No problem :)